# Avalonia: Binding Command Property to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, avaloniaui

So I created a custom button control, let's call it `MyButton`, using Avalonia. `MyButton` is a collection of several controls including a `Avalonia.Controls.Button` looking like this (`MyButton.xaml`):

```
<Border xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        .....
        x:Class="myProject.myControls.MyButton">
  <Button x:Name="button"
          Background="Transparent"
          ....
          BorderThickness="0">
    <Panel >
      .....
    </Panel>
  </Button>
</Border>
```

(Yes my custom control inherits from `Avalonia.Controls.Border` instead of `Avalonia.Controls.UserControl`)

My plan is to pass the buttons `Command` property (the one with the `x:Name="button"` attribute) further up and make it accessable via `MyButton`.

So when I want to use `MyButton` in the `MainWindow.xaml` I'd to be able to do the following:

```
<Window ... >
   <Design.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
   </Design.DataContext>
   <myControls:MyButton Command="{Binding MyButton_Click}"/>
</Window>
```

where the view model `MainWindowViewModel.cs` looks like this:

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public void MyButton_Click()
    {
         // do stuff...
    }
}
```

The way I tried to do this in `MyButton.xaml.cs` is the following:

```
public class MyButton : Border
{
    private readonly Button button;

    public MyButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button = this.FindControl<Button>("button");
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }

    public static readonly StyledProperty<ICommand> CommandProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<MyButton, ICommand>(nameof(Command));


    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set
        { // this setter is never executed as can be seen when running with debugger attached
            if (button != null) 
            {
                button.Command = value;
                SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("MyButton error: unable to set Command: control not initialized!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when running the application and clicking the button the target method `MyButton_Click` is never executed. Attaching the debugger it seems like the `MyButton.Command` setter is never executed either, which I think would be due to incorrect Binding? (There are no binding errors or anything related to this on the debug console)

After a few hours of trial and error I found a workaround using Reflection and a custom `OnClick()` Eventhandler on the `button` element. It works but is kinda ugly and requires a static target method so my question is:

**How does one properly bind a Command on a UserControl to a method contained in the ViewModel of the main Window?**

Also: Could my reflection-based approach also be viable? (I assume Avalonia bindings are also based on reflection somehow?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use getters and setters for styled properties, they **won't** be called when property is altered via bindings, styles or animations (it's the same for WPF, UWP and Xamarin.Forms). Instead you need to either bind your nested Button's command via `<Button Command="{Binding $parent[myControls:MyButton]}" />` (preferable) or subscribe to property change notification from the static constructor like the original `Button` [does](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/7752bc03687641501a62811202bb2bcf9644d814/src/Avalonia.Controls/Button.cs#L88).

More on dependency properties (which work mostly the same way as StyledProperty in Avalonia): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview

Comment: I see. I actually looked up how it was done in the implementation of the original `Button` (the one you also linked) and ended up using a `DirectProperty` like so: `public static readonly DirectProperty<MyButton, ICommand> CommandProperty = AvaloniaProperty.RegisterDirect<MyButton, ICommand>(nameof(Command), button => button.Command, (button, command) => button.Command = command, enableDataValidation: true);` which fixed it. As I am not that familiar with avalonia, I wonder if that works too or has this approach any other drawbacks that I am not aware of?

Comment: Direct properties are used for cases where priority value system isn't required (i. e. the property will always have one value). You can read more about direct properties here: http://avaloniaui.net/docs/authoring-controls/defining-properties

Comment: Link correction (above is now 404): https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/authoring-controls/defining-properties